# Strange Behavior when ObservableCollection is binded to ListView on Asynchronous Command Execution

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, asynchronous, observablecollection

I have read many posts on binding an ObservableCollection to a ListView from people with similar issues; however, I haven't found a solution for my usecase, yet.

In the following test application, I have a simple ListView and a Button. On startup, the ListView is initialized, i.e. 2 columns and 30 rows with values from 0-29 are created. Half of the 30 rows (i.e. 15 rows) are visible. To see the remaining 15 Items I have to scroll down using the Scrollbar.

The Button is binded to an Asynchronous Command using the *AsynchronousCommand* Class from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM). When the button is clicked (see *Start_Click*), random numbers are written into those 30 rows of the ListView. This is done in an endless loop of a separate Thread (see *AsynchronousCommand*).

Now, when I click on the button, I would expect all ListView Items to change to random values instantaneously. However, this is not what's happening. Instead, only those Items that are not visible (i.e. the 15 Items beyond the ScrollBar) are changing their values. Sometimes, none of the Items changes its value.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="614">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="38*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Height="261" Margin="28,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="325" Header="Data" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Data}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Start" Command="{Binding StartCommand}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21.043,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my Code (View's CodeBehind, ViewModel, Controller Logic, and Model):

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the CodeBehind of my View
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is my ViewModel
/// </summary>
public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    private ObservableCollection<Document> _myList;
    private Logic _logic;
    private AsynchronousCommand _startCommand;        

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _myList = new ObservableCollection<Document>();
        _logic = new Logic(this);
        _startCommand = new AsynchronousCommand(_logic.Start_Click, true);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Document> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set
        {
            if (_myList != value)
            {
                _myList = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("MyList");
            }
        }
    }

    public AsynchronousCommand StartCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _startCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            _startCommand = value;
        }
    }
}

public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is my Controller
/// </summary>
public class Logic
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;
    private Random _rnd;

    public Logic(ViewModel vm)
    {
        _viewModel = vm;
        _rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Document newDocument = new Document("Name " + i.ToString(), "Data " + i.ToString());
            _viewModel.MyList.Add(newDocument);
        } 
    }

    public void Start_Click(object obj)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int idx = _rnd.Next(0, 29);

            _viewModel.StartCommand.ReportProgress(() =>
            {
                _viewModel.MyList[idx].Name = "New Name";
                _viewModel.MyList[idx].Data = "New Data";
            });

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is my Model
/// </summary>
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public Document(string name, string data)
    {
        Name = name;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

And this is the Code for my AsynchronousCommand, taken from [Dave Kerr's article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM):

```
/// <summary>
/// The ViewModelCommand class - an ICommand that can fire a function.
/// </summary>
public class Command : ICommand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Command"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The action.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">if set to <c>true</c> [can execute].</param>
    public Command(Action action, bool canExecute = true)
    {
        // Set the action.
        this.action = action;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Command"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameterizedAction">The parameterized action.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">if set to <c>true</c> [can execute].</param>
    public Command(Action<object> parameterizedAction, bool canExecute = true)
    {
        // Set the action.
        this.parameterizedAction = parameterizedAction;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param">The param.</param>
    public virtual void DoExecute(object param)
    {
        // Invoke the executing command, allowing the command to be cancelled.
        CancelCommandEventArgs args = new CancelCommandEventArgs() { Parameter = param, Cancel = false };
        InvokeExecuting(args);
        // If the event has been cancelled, bail now.
        if (args.Cancel)
            return;
        // Call the action or the parameterized action, whichever has been set.
        InvokeAction(param);
        // Call the executed function.
        InvokeExecuted(new CommandEventArgs() { Parameter = param });
    }

    protected void InvokeAction(object param)
    {
        Action theAction = action;
        Action<object> theParameterizedAction = parameterizedAction;
        if (theAction != null)
            theAction();
        else if (theParameterizedAction != null)
            theParameterizedAction(param);
    }

    protected void InvokeExecuted(CommandEventArgs args)
    {
        CommandEventHandler executed = Executed;
        // Call the executed event.
        if (executed != null)
            executed(this, args);
    }

    protected void InvokeExecuting(CancelCommandEventArgs args)
    {
        CancelCommandEventHandler executing = Executing;
        // Call the executed event.
        if (executing != null)
            executing(this, args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The action (or parameterized action) that will be called when the command is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    protected Action action = null;
    protected Action<object> parameterizedAction = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Bool indicating whether the command can execute.
    /// </summary>
    private bool canExecute = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance can execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <c>true</c> if this instance can execute; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool CanExecute
    {
        get { return canExecute; }
        set
        {
            if (canExecute != value)
            {
                canExecute = value;
                EventHandler canExecuteChanged = CanExecuteChanged;
                if (canExecuteChanged != null)
                    canExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// 
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.DoExecute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion


    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when can execute is changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the command is about to execute.
    /// </summary>
    public event CancelCommandEventHandler Executing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the command executed.
    /// </summary>
    public event CommandEventHandler Executed;
}

/// <summary>
/// The CommandEventHandler delegate.
/// </summary>
public delegate void CommandEventHandler(object sender, CommandEventArgs args);

/// <summary>
/// The CancelCommandEvent delegate.
/// </summary>
public delegate void CancelCommandEventHandler(object sender, CancelCommandEventArgs args);

/// <summary>
/// CommandEventArgs - simply holds the command parameter.
/// </summary>
public class CommandEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The parameter.</value>
    public object Parameter { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// CancelCommandEventArgs - just like above but allows the event to
/// be cancelled.
/// </summary>
public class CancelCommandEventArgs : CommandEventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="CancelCommandEventArgs"/> command should be cancelled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if cancel; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// The AsynchronousCommand is a Command that runs on a thread from the thread pool.
/// </summary>
public class AsynchronousCommand : Command, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsynchronousCommand"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The action.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">if set to <c>true</c> the command can execute.</param>
    public AsynchronousCommand(Action action, bool canExecute = true)
        : base(action, canExecute)
    {
        // Initialise the command.
        Initialise();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AsynchronousCommand"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameterizedAction">The parameterized action.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">if set to <c>true</c> [can execute].</param>
    public AsynchronousCommand(Action<object> parameterizedAction, bool canExecute = true)
        : base(parameterizedAction, canExecute)
    {
        // Initialise the command.
        Initialise();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises this instance.
    /// </summary>
    private void Initialise()
    {
        // Construct the cancel command.
        cancelCommand = new Command(
        () =>
        {
            // Set the Is Cancellation Requested flag.
            IsCancellationRequested = true;
        }, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param">The param.</param>
    public override void DoExecute(object param)
    {
        // If we are already executing, do not continue.
        if (IsExecuting)
            return;
        // Invoke the executing command, allowing the command to be cancelled.
        CancelCommandEventArgs args = new CancelCommandEventArgs() { Parameter = param, Cancel = false };
        InvokeExecuting(args);
        // If the event has been cancelled, bail now.
        if (args.Cancel)
            return;
        // We are executing.
        IsExecuting = true;

        // Store the calling dispatcher.
        callingDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        // Run the action on a new thread from the thread pool (this will therefore work in SL and WP7 as well).
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        (state) =>
        {
            // Invoke the action.
            InvokeAction(param);
            // Fire the executed event and set the executing state.
            ReportProgress(
            () =>
            {
                // We are no longer executing.
                IsExecuting = false;
                // If we were cancelled, invoke the cancelled event - otherwise invoke executed.
                if (IsCancellationRequested)
                    InvokeCancelled(new CommandEventArgs() { Parameter = param });
                else
                    InvokeExecuted(new CommandEventArgs() { Parameter = param });
                // We are no longer requesting cancellation.
                IsCancellationRequested = false;
            }
            );
        }
        );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the property changed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // Store the event handler - in case it changes between
        // the line to check it and the line to fire it.
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        // If the event has been subscribed to, fire it.
        if (propertyChanged != null)
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reports progress on the thread which invoked the command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The action.</param>
    public void ReportProgress(Action action)
    {
        if (IsExecuting)
        {
            if (callingDispatcher.CheckAccess())
                action();
            else
                callingDispatcher.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => { action(); })));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cancels the command if requested.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if the command has been cancelled and we must return.</returns>
    public bool CancelIfRequested()
    {
        // If we haven't requested cancellation, there's nothing to do.
        if (IsCancellationRequested == false)
            return false;
        // We're done.
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes the cancelled event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">The <see cref="Apex.MVVM.CommandEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void InvokeCancelled(CommandEventArgs args)
    {
        CommandEventHandler cancelled = Cancelled;
        // Call the cancelled event.
        if (cancelled != null)
            cancelled(this, args);
    }

    protected Dispatcher callingDispatcher;

    /// <summary>
    /// Flag indicating that the command is executing.
    /// </summary>
    private bool isExecuting = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Flag indicated that cancellation has been requested.
    /// </summary>
    private bool isCancellationRequested;

    /// <summary>
    /// The cancel command.
    /// </summary>
    private Command cancelCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// The property changed event.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the command is cancelled.
    /// </summary>
    public event CommandEventHandler Cancelled;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is executing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <c>true</c> if this instance is executing; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool IsExecuting
    {
        get
        {
            return isExecuting;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isExecuting != value)
            {
                isExecuting = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsExecuting");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is cancellation requested.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <c>true</c> if this instance is cancellation requested; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool IsCancellationRequested
    {
        get
        {
            return isCancellationRequested;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isCancellationRequested != value)
            {
                isCancellationRequested = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsCancellationRequested");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the cancel command.
    /// </summary>
    public Command CancelCommand
    {
        get { return cancelCommand; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for me to understand: Why are you not using Async/Await Pattern with Async Binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Document` Class has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface so the UI gets updated once your **Properties** change.

**Why is it working when you scroll?**
Because of `Virtualization`. Not visible entries have not been evualuated yet, so once they get evaluated they already receive the "New Value".

Here is your Document class that works:

```
/// <summary>
    /// This is my Model
    /// </summary>
    public class Document : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _data;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set
            {
                _data = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Document(string name, string data)
        {
            Name = name;
            Data = data;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```